# Trying to normalize Python image getting error - RGB values must be in the 0..1 range

Tags: python, image-processing, normalization

I'm given an image (32, 32, 3) and two vectors (3,) that represent mean and std.  I'm trying normalize the image by getting the image into a state where I can subtract the mean and divide by the std but I'm getting the following error when I try to plot it.

```
ValueError: Floating point image RGB values must be in the 0..1 range.
```

I understand the error so I'm thinking I'm not performing the correct operations when I try to normalize.  Below is the code I'm trying to use normalize the image.

```
mean.shape #(3,)
std.shape #(3,)
sample.shape #(32,32,3)

# trying to unroll and by RGB channels
channel_1 = sample[:, :, 0].ravel()
channel_2 = sample[:, :, 1].ravel()
channel_3 = sample[:, :, 2].ravel()

# Putting the vectors together so I can try to normalize
rbg_matrix = np.column_stack((channel_1,channel_2,channel_3))

# Trying to normalize
rbg_matrix = rbg_matrix - mean
rbg_matrix = rbg_matrix / std

# Trying to put back in "image" form
rgb_image = np.reshape(rbg_matrix,(32,32,3))
```

Comment: And what happens to the values that are further away from the mean than one std?

Comment: can you provide the whole stack trace?

Answer (score 7):

Your error seems to point to a lack of normalization of the image.

I've used this function to normalize images in my Deep Learning projects

```
def normalize(x):
    """
    Normalize a list of sample image data in the range of 0 to 1
    : x: List of image data.  The image shape is (32, 32, 3)
    : return: Numpy array of normalized data
    """
    return np.array((x - np.min(x)) / (np.max(x) - np.min(x)))
```

Comment: @user2743 Hello there...

If you found my answer useful please upvote it and / or mark it as solution.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Normalizing an image by setting its mean to zero and its standard deviation to 1, as you do, leads to an image where a majority, but not all, of the pixels are in the range [-2,2]. This is perfectly valid for further processing, and often explicitly applied in certain machine learning methods. I have seen it referred to as "whitening", but is more properly called a [standardization transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitening_transformation).

It seems that the plotting function you use expects the image to be in the range [0,1]. This is a limitation of the plotting function, not of your normalization. [Other image display functions](https://github.com/DIPlib/diplib) would be perfectly able to show your image.

To normalize to the [0,1] range you should not use the mean and standard deviation, but the maximum and the minimum, as shown in [Pitto's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49429842/7328782).