# numpy.empty() data type not understood error on Google colab

Tags: python, numpy, exception, pytorch, google-colaboratory

numpy.empty() returns data type not understood exception on Google colab's default numpy library. I checked all questions in stackoverflow but didnt see related to this problem since i am using google colab. Here is full code and exception output:

**Full code:**

```
def diffMask(img1=None, img2=None, opt=None, dataset=None, args=None):
    netG = args[0]
    netB = args[1]
    netD = args[2]
    f = args[3]
    res_path = opt.results_Stage3
    res_folders = ['temp_masks',
                   'temp_Stage2',
                   'temp_ref',
                   'temp_diff',
                   'temp_Stage3',
                   'temp_skel',
                   'temp_res',
                   'temp_Stage1',
                   'temp_src']
    for x in res_folders:
        if os.path.isdir("{}{}".format(res_path, x)) == False:
            os.mkdir("{}{}".format(res_path, x))
    save_masks = "{}{}".format(res_path, "temp_masks")
    save_Stage2 = "{}{}".format(res_path, "temp_Stage2")
    save_ref = "{}{}".format(res_path, "temp_ref")
    save_diff = "{}{}".format(res_path, "temp_diff")
    save_Stage3 = "{}{}".format(res_path, "temp_Stage3")
    save_skel = "{}{}".format(res_path, "temp_skel")
    save_res = "{}{}".format(res_path, "temp_res")
    save_Stage1 = "{}{}".format(res_path, "temp_Stage1")
    save_src = "{}{}".format(res_path, "temp_src")

    resize2 = transforms.Resize(size=(128, 128))
    src, mask, style_img, target, gt_cloth, skel, cloth = dataset.get_img("{}_0.jpg".format(img1[:-6]),
                                                                          "{}_1.jpg".format(img1[:-6]))
    src, mask, style_img, target, gt_cloth, skel, cloth = src.unsqueeze(0), mask.unsqueeze(0), style_img.unsqueeze(
        0), target.unsqueeze(0), gt_cloth.unsqueeze(0), skel.unsqueeze(0), cloth.unsqueeze(0)  # , face.unsqueeze(0)
    src1, mask1, style_img1, target1, gt_cloth1, skel1, cloth1 = Variable(src.cuda()), Variable(mask.cuda()), Variable(
        style_img.cuda()), Variable(target.cuda()), Variable(gt_cloth.cuda()), Variable(skel.cuda()), Variable(
        cloth.cuda())  # , Variable(face.cuda())
    src, mask, style_img, target, gt_cloth, skel, cloth = dataset.get_img("{}_0.jpg".format(img2[:-6]),
                                                                          "{}_1.jpg".format(img2[:-6]))
    src, mask, style_img, target, gt_cloth, skel, cloth = src.unsqueeze(0), mask.unsqueeze(0), style_img.unsqueeze(
        0), target.unsqueeze(0), gt_cloth.unsqueeze(0), skel.unsqueeze(0), cloth.unsqueeze(0)  # , face.unsqueeze(0)
    src2, mask2, style_img2, target2, gt_cloth2, skel2, cloth2 = Variable(src.cuda()), Variable(mask.cuda()), Variable(
        style_img.cuda()), Variable(target.cuda()), Variable(gt_cloth.cuda()), Variable(skel.cuda()), Variable(
        cloth.cuda())

    gen_targ_Stage1, s_128, s_64, s_32, s_16, s_8, s_4 = netG(skel1, cloth2)  # gen_targ11 is structural change cloth
    gen_targ_Stage2, s_128, s_64, s_32, s_16, s_8, s_4 = netB(src1, gen_targ_Stage1,
                                                              skel1)  # gen_targ12 is Stage2 image

    # saving structural 
    pic_Stage2 = (torch.cat([gen_targ_Stage2], dim=0).data + 1) / 2.0
    #     save_dir = "/home/np9207/PolyGan_res/temp_Stage2/"
    save_image(pic_Stage2, '%s/%d_%s_%d.jpg' % (save_Stage2, f, img1[:-6], 0), nrow=1)

    msk1 = mask1[0, :, :, :].detach().cpu().permute(1, 2, 0)
    plt.imsave("{}/{}_{}_mask.jpg".format(save_masks, f, img1[:-6]), msk1, cmap="gray")
```

**I got exception on this line:**

```
plt.imsave("{}/{}_{}_mask.jpg".format(save_masks, f, img1[:-6]), msk1, cmap="gray")
```

**Exception Output:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 208, in test
    diffMask(image1, image2, opt, test_loader, args)
  File "test.py", line 96, in diffMask
    plt.imsave("{}/{}_{}_mask.jpg".format(save_masks, f, img1[:-6]), msk1, cmap="gray")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2066, in imsave
    return matplotlib.image.imsave(fname, arr, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 1550, in imsave
    rgba = sm.to_rgba(arr, bytes=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/cm.py", line 217, in to_rgba
    xx = np.empty(shape=(m, n, 4), dtype=x.dtype)
TypeError: data type not understood
```

**Numpy Version :** `1.18.5`

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is a problem with the arguments you're passing to the `imsave` call. Check what you're passing, and compare those arguments to the documentation for `imsave`.

Comment: Looks like you're using some kind of GPU computation library and trying to use its types with `imsave`. `imsave` takes image data as a NumPy array or arraylike. You seem to be passing something else.

Comment: Did you forget to use `.numpy()` on your img1 tensor?

Comment: Thanks for comments. It looks like caused by not passing array to `.imsave` but when i checked to arguments:
`"{}/{}_{}_mask.jpg".format(save_masks, f, img1[:-6])` ->path of image. string //
`msk1"` -> tensor, array
what should i do for fix it?

Comment: I'd define `filename="{}/{}_{}_mask.jpg".format(save_masks, f, img1[:-6])` in a separate line.  That make the `imsave` call clearer.  Then focus on `msk`.  Docs says that should be "The image data", array like 2 or 3d.

Comment: @hpaulj Yeah i see. I tried to check what kind of array is msk1 so `msk1.size()` returns `torch.Size([128, 128, 3])` It looks 3D array

Comment: But what does `np.asarray(msk1)` do.  `matplotlib` doesn't "know" about `torch`, so it just tries a "dumb" conversion to array.  I'd suggest doing your own proper conversion to `ndarray` first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@user2357112](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2357112/user2357112-supports-monica) [@Rika](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2736559/rika) and [@hpaulj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/901925/hpaulj) 's great helps, I found the cause of the problem and here is solution for those who is struggling  the same issue:

```
msk1 = msk1.numpy()
```

But then (probably) you will get `ValueError: Floating point image RGB values must be in the 0..1 range.` exception. You have to normalize your array. Thanks to [him](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49429842/11143781)

```
def normalize(x):
    """
    Normalize a list of sample image data in the range of 0 to 1
    : x: List of image data.  The image shape is (32, 32, 3)
    : return: Numpy array of normalized data
    """
    return np.array((x - np.min(x)) / (np.max(x) - np.min(x)))

msk1 = normalize(msk1.numpy())
```